how to rotate just the consumerSecret on a connected app?
For a Connected App in Salesforce, can the consumerSecret be updated or changed apart from the consumerKey? And, can this be done programmatically? This documentation only gives a path through the UI, and only for updating the consumerSecret and the consumerKey at the same time:
Rotate the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret of a Connected App
The problem is that after that process, getting the new key and secret out of Salesforce seems very manual and therefore would introduce the possibility of human error.
Is it true that rotating just the secret is a general feature and practice for many other platforms or is forcing both to change together normal in the industry? For example, this question and and answer don't mention the consumerKey at all:
 Should Client Secret for oAuth be rotated?
And documentation for other platforms often only describes rotating the secret.

You're asking broad, opinion-based questions - not a good fit for this site. Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Possible answers to your question have significant pros/cons and depend on threat assessment of your entire ecosystem. Is rotating the consumer key along with the secret better than rotating only the secret. It depends on who you ask.

I'll accept an answer in format of "a consumerSecret on a connected app cannot be updated independent from the consumer key as per the link in the original question" , or "the consumerSecret on a connected app can be updated programmatically via Apex or REST as per this alternate link..".

No, you can't update either one programmatically, allowing to do so is a major threat vector. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm

For clarity, automating the functionality represented by the "Generate" and "Apply" buttons is what I meant by updating. I don't want to provide values for those fields or attributes directly.
Still, rotating just the consumerSecret on a connected app is the main question.

No, you can't rotate only the consumer secret. You can create a new connected app programmatically with your own secret and then update the relying parties. This can work for some scenarios.
